# Placeholder for contacts without name in listview

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, cursor, simplecursoradapter

I have a listview that displays contacts. This is populated using a `SimpleCursorAdapter`. A contact's name is what will appear on the listview - so if the contact does not have a name, then the listview item will still appear, but without any text - thus displaying a blank row and confusing the user.

I get a list of contacts from my database using this method:

```
public static List<Customer> getcustomerList()
        {
            try
            {
                List<Customer> customerList = new ArrayList<Customer>();
                Cursor cursor = getAllCustomers();
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        Customer cust = new Customer();
                        cust.customerId = UUID.fromString(cursor.getString(0));
                        cust.firstName = cursor.getString(1);
                        cust.lastName = cursor.getString(2);
                        customerList.add(cust);
                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }
                return customerList;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Which is called from my activity, here:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cust_list);
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        setupActionBar();
        populateListView();
    }

private void populateListView() {
        Cursor cursor = Db.Functions.getCustomerList();
        String[] cols = new String[] {
                "Name", "MobileNumber" };
        int[] to = new int[] {
                R.id.lblCustName, R.id.lblNumber };
        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this, R.layout.customer_info, cursor, cols, to, 0);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.custlist);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view, int position, long id) {
                try
                {
                    // Called when an individual item is pressed on customer list
                    Gen.vib(CustomApp.app, 15);
                    Cursor searchCursor = (Cursor) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    String idString = searchCursor.getString(searchCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"));
                    Intent intent = new Intent(CustomApp.app, ViewCustomerActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("uuid", idString);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, CODE_VIEWCUSTOMER);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

### Question

What is the cleanest, most efficient way of making my listview display "Unnamed Customer" when their name is blank? (Without storing them as such in the database)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to check it, when you reading your database:

```
public static List<Customer> getcustomerList()
    {
        try
        {
            List<Customer> customerList = new ArrayList<Customer>();
            Cursor cursor = getAllCustomers();
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    Customer cust = new Customer();
                    cust.customerId = UUID.fromString(cursor.getString(0));
                     //Check if custumer has no name neither lastname:
                    if(cursor.getString(1).isEmpty() && cursor.getString(2).isEmpty()){
                      cust.firstName = "Unnamed Customer";
                   }
                   else{ 
                    cust.firstName = cursor.getString(1);
                    cust.lastName = cursor.getString(2);
                   }
                    customerList.add(cust);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            return customerList;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

But I think, that better solution is to use `custom Cursor Adapter`. In that case, you can decide what to do with each item according to its data.